# Reading server-side files using Blazor

Tags: c#, web, .net-core, webassembly, blazor

I have a project based on the Blazor sample with a `.Client`, `.Server` and `.Shared` projects. I have a textfile `data.txt` on the server that I want to be able to read/write using standard `StreamReader` / `System.IO.File` methods. Since Blazor runs in a sandbox I guess I can't access the entire filesystem as I would in a normal windows app? I've placed the file in the `wwwroot` directory, and I can even access the file from the client if a enter `url/data.txt` in the browser so the file gets served, which I don't want to alow, but trying to read that file as such:

```
var file = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
```

Results in the error:

```
WASM: [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] Could not find file "/data.txt"
```

How can I read server-side files and keep them hidden from the client?

Comment: Blazor runs in the client. It can't access the server. It will need to make a HTTP request to the server to get its data.

Comment: rephrased question for clarity, as it's meant as one question. @mjwills If all the pages are run on the client, maybe I could set up a controller class on the server that can access the files?

Comment: `and keep them hidden from the client?` What do you mean by `the client`? Do you mean `the browser`? **Why** don't you want the client to see it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out this was easier than I thought. I was approaching it from the wrong angle. To access server side files, create a controller as such:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Favlist.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataFetcher : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public MyDataClass GetData(string action, string id)
        {
            var str = File.ReadAllText("data.txt");
            return new MyDataClass(str);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it within your page like so:

```
@using System.IO;
@page "/dataview"
@inject HttpClient Http

@if (data == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p>@data.Name</p>
}

@functions {
    MyDataClass data;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        data = await Http.GetJsonAsync<MyDataClass>("api/DataFetcher/GetData");
    }
}
```

`MyDataClass` is your custom class containing whatever you need to read/write.

You can then access files exactly as you normally would, wherever you want on the server. The current directory is your Project.Server root folder.

Comment: My Blazor Server-Side project does not recognize the DataAccess type.

"The Type of namespace name DataClass could not be found. Are you missing a using directive...."

Does this only work with client-side Blazor?

Comment: What is DataClass?  I added a new controller to the server and Visual Studio has no clue what this is. Please edit your response

Comment: @softwareisfun The DataClass is your custom class containing whatever you want to read/write, implementation should be fairly straightforward as you can see in the controller implementation example. I updated the answer for a bit more clarity. Hope that helps!

Comment: Just a typo there - File.ReadAllTest should be Text, not to confuse others (after plenty of trials and errors that red line when I copied the code was flustrating :D ). Also the File is System.IO.File, not ControllerBase.File. It took me a while till I found that out too ;)

Comment: This answer is missing a lot of information, and calling your own API is impossible using this answer. For example, how do you configure the base URI?

Answer (score 6):

To read a server-side file placed in your project, use like this :

`File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"wwwroot","data.txt"));`

Article : https://www.peug.net/en/reading-server-side-files-using-blazor/

Answer (score 3):

**WASM: [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] Could not find file "/data.txt"** is the standard message displayed by Blazor when you try to access a local file on the client.
Reading from files or writing into files is not allowed by design, as it's a violation of the sandbox, commonly shared by Web Assembly and JavaScript.

On the server you can create a Web API that can locally access your files, whether Json, text, database, etc., and returns results in a variety of formats to the calling Blazor methods. You may restrict access to the data in these files, using authentication and authorization.

Hope this helps...

Comment: can you provide an example of creating a WebAPI to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can read the file from wwwroot folder in blazor webassembly app.
Use this code to read your file

```js
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(@"sample-data/test.xml");
```

Comment: I use Blazor WebAssembly APP, however when I use your method I get: System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set. - I Use for a client HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();